# How to get VM backup status via Proxmox VE API?

Tags: rest, api, backup, proxmox

Using the Proxmox VE API I want to get status information for all all configured **backup jobs** (those you can find below `cluster/backup/{id}/`). There I can see *which VMs* are being backed up and *when* the backup should take place but I can't see the status of the last backup (better would be last N).

What I need is information like this:

```
VMID  |   Job-ID  |             Started | Status | Duration  |   Size
 123  | a39..8ab  | 2020-01-16 00:00:02 |     OK |     1:23  | 7.81GB
 131  | f3h..ab4  | 2020-01-16 00:00:02 |     OK |     0:37  | 1.23GB
```

What I *can* see is a list of tasks which have been run on a given node, say `node/{node}/tasks/{upid}/status|log`. There I find an *exit status* and a *console log*:

```
INFO: starting new backup job: vzdump 101 102 103 104 105 100 --compress lzo --quiet 1 --storage QNAP --mailnotification always --mode snapshot --mailto ***@**.com
INFO: Starting Backup of VM 100 (qemu)
INFO: Backup started at 2020-01-16 00:00:02
INFO: status = running
INFO: update VM 100: -lock backup
INFO: VM Name: ****.**.tribe29.com
INFO: include disk 'scsi0' 'local-zfs:vm-100-disk-0' 60G
INFO: backup mode: snapshot
INFO: ionice priority: 7
INFO: creating archive '/mnt/pve/QNAP/dump/vzdump-qemu-100-2020_01_16-00_00_02.vma.lzo'
INFO: started backup task 'd9f7c327-e610-4e38-931e-2251c9548e76'
INFO: status: 0% (319356928/64424509440), sparse 0% (115822592), duration 4, read/write 79/50 MB/s
INFO: status: 1% (678428672/64424509440), sparse 0% (151867392), duration 7, read/write 119/107 MB/s
INFO: status: 2% (1372258304/64424509440), sparse 0% (212226048), duration 17, read/write 69/63 MB/s
...
INFO: status: 98% (63369576448/64424509440), sparse 85% (54797918208), duration 164, read/write 399/86 MB/s
INFO: status: 100% (64424509440/64424509440), sparse 86% (55852843008), duration 165, read/write 1054/0 MB/s
INFO: transferred 64424 MB in 165 seconds (390 MB/s)
INFO: archive file size: 4.53GB
```

Relevant data I *could* get from here (by parsing the log):

- VMID: 100
- started at 2020-01-16 00:00:02"
- '/mnt/pve/QNAP/dump/vzdump-qemu-100-2020_01_16-00_00_02.vma.lzo'
- backup task 'd9f7c327-e610-4e38-931e-2251c9548e76'
- 64424 MB
- 165 seconds (390 MB/s)
- archive file size: 4.53GB
- exit status via `node/{node}/tasks/{upid}/status`

What I'm missing:

- a way to link `node/{node}/tasks/{upid}` to `cluster/backup/{id}` (for me `node/{node}/tasks/{upid}/status/id` is always empty)
- I'm not sure whether the task I'm looking for is still there or if it has been cleaned up already
- I have to parse the log manually which is error prone and might change in the future

So is there a way for me to get information like this via the API directly:?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there's nothing like this - you would have to parse the log-entries you can retrieve via API on `nodes/{node}/tasks/{upid}/log`.

If you need to now how: Checkmk reads the logs for internal purposes, you can find the code here: https://github.com/tribe29/checkmk/blob/master/cmk/special_agents/agent_proxmox.py, in the class `BackupTask`.

Disclaimer: I'm tribe29 employee and wrote this code *after* posting this question.